# Why type of drywall-like material to use on a gas fireplace?

Tags: drywall, walls, heating, fireplace, chimney

## Context

I am remodeling an addition with a gas fireplace. The gas fireplace manufacturer recommends to not use drywall as high as 12in above the firebox. I am looking for a material that is similar to drywall, to be placed 3 in above the firebox, that would not deform or deteriorate with exposure to heat. My research has been inconclusive. Some sort of ceramic fiber board would work, but my local supplier does not carry this product.

## Requirements

1. Material/product must be heat resistant and not deform/deteriorate.
2. Material depth must match surrounding drywall 1/2in.
3. Material must be coverable with heat resistant mud to make it flush and flat with surrounding drywall

## Question

What type of material(s) can I use?

Comment: I would re-read the fireplace instructions.  Most heaters have a minimum open space around them in certain directions so walls/ceilings/floors do not get too hot.

Comment: The area that I am looking to cover is closed, but recessed by 1/2in. I am looking to make it flush/flat with the wall.

Comment: Pictures will help.  Blocking any ventilation openings is bad, and there might be a reason for the recess.

Comment: I'm removing the 2nd question, as that's off topic. What kind of material seems entirely reasonable, and once you have that info, you'll be able to find someone to sell it to you. Also removing the "local supplier" question as we have no clue where you live or what your suppliers might carry.

Answer (score 3):

Tile backer board / cementboard is fairly standard in this application, since the demise of asbestos-cement board as a product any sane person would use or make/sell.

Comment: Cement and backer board are thermal conductors. How about ceramic fiber boards without asbestos?